# Reactjs how to pass properties:

Tags: reactjs

I am using Griddle custom components and I have a component

```
var someComp = React.createCleass ...
```

then I set the custom component in griddle's config:

```
this.state.config.columns[1].customComponent = someComp;
```

Everything works fine: the only thing is if I want to pass a property in I don't see how? This fails:

```
this.state.config.columns[1].customComponent = <someComp prop1="me"/>;
```

So how do I pass properties to it? In my render I pass the config to Griddle so I never really use the jsx syntax ...